# Hyperlinks not working

Tags: facebook, heroku, facebook-apps

I developeed my facebook app. In that i have added some some links to other pages but on clicking it doesn't redirect to other pages.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pokerFFFFF" title="Amit Singh">Amit Kumar Singh</a>
```

After its failure as  am using heroku so i created a page over there and even try to redirect from there but it is not helping me.
Like i created page pokerfff.php there and try to redirect there

```
<a href="pokerfff.php" title="Amit Singh">Amit Kumar Singh</a>
```

and content of pokerfff.php is

```
<?php

   header( 'Location: https://www.facebook.com/pokerFFFFF' ) ;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should answer my own question.

My code is running under some frame so if i use target= _top in < a> will work like

< a target= _top href="pokerfff.php" title="Amit Singh">Amit Kumar Singh < / a >